# SOS:: Hosted Google Reader Alternative project down on Heroku with timeout H12.

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, timeout

We have built an open-source, free Google Reader Alternative and have live users using the platform. It is hosted at http://reader.pykih.com and code is at http://github.com/pykih/reader

Until, last night my app was working fine and today morning it is down due to timeout.

- We use DelayedJobs for all feed imports
- This timeout is occurring on the homepage where there is no external service call, emails being set, etc. except may be push to GA
- Heroku Support (as per them) is asleep right now and we will get an answer only on Monday. :-(
- We went through a lot of past questions on Stack over flow about this issue but none seem to answer our issue.

Can someone please advice?

```
2013-06-08T04:25:32.596864+00:00 app[worker.1]: [Worker(host:b0f05380-0265-49de-b2c1-df13df269cd6 pid:2)] Starting job worker
2013-06-08T04:25:34.225938+00:00 app[web.1]: Disconnected from ActiveRecord
2013-06-08T04:25:34.225544+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-06-08T04:25:34.225214 #2]  INFO -- : listening on addr=0.0.0.0:33707 fd=7
2013-06-08T04:25:34.250988+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-06-08T04:25:35.246195+00:00 app[web.1]: Disconnected from ActiveRecord
2013-06-08T04:25:35.254585+00:00 app[web.1]: Connected to ActiveRecord
2013-06-08T04:25:35.375559+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-06-08T04:25:35.375194 #5]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
2013-06-08T04:25:36.263576+00:00 app[web.1]: Disconnected from ActiveRecord
2013-06-08T04:25:36.273848+00:00 app[web.1]: Connected to ActiveRecord
2013-06-08T04:25:36.390283+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-06-08T04:25:36.389861 #8]  INFO -- : worker=1 ready
2013-06-08T04:25:37.281171+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-06-08T04:25:37.280925 #2]  INFO -- : master process ready
2013-06-08T04:25:37.291365+00:00 app[web.1]: Connected to ActiveRecord
2013-06-08T04:25:37.416442+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-06-08T04:25:37.415844 #11]  INFO -- : worker=2 ready
2013-06-08T04:25:46.993985+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 120.63.8.230 at 2013-06-08 04:25:46 +0000
2013-06-08T04:26:16.919340+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path=/ host=reader.pykih.com fwd="120.63.8.230" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
2013-06-08T04:26:23.974357+00:00 app[web.1]: E, [2013-06-08T04:26:17.347459 #2] ERROR -- : worker=0 PID:5 timeout (31s > 30s), killing
2013-06-08T04:26:23.975290+00:00 app[web.1]: E, [2013-06-08T04:26:17.376903 #2] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 5 SIGKILL (signal 9)> worker=0
2013-06-08T04:26:23.975290+00:00 app[web.1]: Disconnected from ActiveRecord
2013-06-08T04:26:23.975611+00:00 app[web.1]: Connected to ActiveRecord
2013-06-08T04:26:23.975611+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-06-08T04:26:18.524590 #14]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku fixed itself 11 hours later. V annoying.